# Pandas dataframe ratio of difference of consecutive columns to first value

Tags: python, sql, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have the DataFrame (called `df`)

```
'name'    'order'    'quantity'
'A'       1           10
'A'       2           15
'A'       3           5
'B'       1           2
'B'       2           6
```

What I want is building another dataframe containing a column with the ratio of the differences of consecutive columns (consecutive in terms of column `order`) to the first value.

I am easily able to retrieve the difference in said ratio (the numerator) as

```
def compute_diff(x):

    quantity_diff = x.quantity.diff()

    return quantity_diff

diff_df = df.sort_values('order').groupby('name').apply(compute_diff).reset_index(name='diff')
```

This gives me

```
'name'    'level_1'    'quantity'
'A'       0           NaN
'A'       1           5
'A'       1           -10
'B'       1           NaN
'B'       2           4
```

Now I want the ratio instead, as per description. Specifically, I'd want

```
'name'    'level_1'    'quantity'
'A'       1           NaN
'A'       2           0.5
'A'       3           -0.6666
'B'       1           NaN
'B'       2           2
```

How to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After performing your `groupby`, use `pct_change`:

```
# Sort the DataFrame, if necessary.
df = df.sort_values(['name', 'order'])

# Use groupby and pcnt_change on the 'quantity' column.
df['quantity'] = df.groupby('name')['quantity'].pct_change()
```

The resulting output:

```
  name  order  quantity
0    A      1       NaN
1    A      2  0.500000
2    A      3 -0.666667
3    B      1       NaN
4    B      2  2.000000
```

Answer (score 2):

You could take your result and divide it by the shifted 'quantity' column in df:

```
diff_df.quantity = diff_df.quantity / df.quantity.shift(1)
```